# OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.What to do?

Tags: python, sockets

I created a simple socket program by python by creating two different files Server.py and a Client.py and tried to connect it by `s.connect((host,port))` but

```
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

occurs

I have looked up many solutions on the net regarding this issue which could be due to Firewall issues, Malware in system, outbound firewall settings , Run by Administrator, even checked if the port was not in use by netstat in cmd but none of them solved my issue.

plz help

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT84e.png)

This is my code:

```
#SERVER.py
import socket

s= socket.socket()
host= socket.gethostname()
port = 5000
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
print(host)
print('Waiting for any incoming connections...')
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(addr,'Has connected to the server')

#CLIENT.py
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host=input('Enter host address:')
port=5000
s.connect((host,port))
print('Connected...')
```

Comment: please paste the text in the "Error Image" in your answer, instead.

Comment: Will take care from next time..thnx
Would be grateful if any solution could be recommended

Comment: Your code looks good to me. If executed on Windows (looks like it is), you should try the following : Run it as administrator, disable antivirus software. if executed on Linux, try disabling apparmor / selinux.

Comment: @OphirCarmi
Tried that but no result

Comment: Take care of it rom *this* time. Otherwise your question is going to get closed, sure as shootin'.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne yeah..looking like that only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try localhost, if host is not working. Like for eg. host='127.0.0.1' #( The server's hostname or IP address)and use a port >1023 (As those are non-privileged ports)
If its still not working, you can try changing your network and try the same steps. If any further issue occurs regarding the same error there must be a issue with your system, for that try factory reset. Then it will work 100%
Best of luck.